# Update a Temporary Table before showing?

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'd like to find out how to update a temporary table before I show the query. This is to avoid making permanent changes to the database.

So far I got the following:

```
WITH
new_salary AS
(SELECT ID,NAME,DEPT_NAME,SALARY FROM INSTRUCTOR WHERE DEPT_NAME='Comp. Sci.')
SELECT
    *
FROM
  new_salary
WHERE
  DEPT_NAME='Comp. Sci.';
```

Now here is where it ends. I want to update this temporary table and show the updated version of that table as to avoid changing the actual database. All my attempts at using the `UPDATE` clause have failed so I am kind of dumbfounded :/

This part I am currently trying to do is not part of homework. It's just me who doesn't want to have to re-do the database over and over.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have two options:

1. [You make a procedure](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_6009.htm), which first checks whether it needs to update the table. After calling that you execute the query.
2. You create a [pipelined function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14289/dcitblfns.htm), which does the checking and returning of the data. You could integrate this into the select like this (pipelined function name called `pipelined_function_name`):

   ```
   select *
   from   table(pipelined_function_name)
   ;
   ```